# Keep getting a ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

My assignment:

> Write a short Python function, minmax(data), that takes a sequence
>   of one or more numbers, and returns the smallest and largest numbers,
>   in the form of a tuple of length two. Do not use the built-in
>   functions min or max in implementing your solution.

Here's the code:

```
def minmax():
    data = input("Enter a list of any input > ")
    max, min = data[0]
    for x in data:
        if x > max:
            max = x
        elif x < min:
            min = x
    print (max, min)
minmax()
```

This gives me `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.
How do I fix this?

Comment: you probably need to do `input('').split()` if the user is entering data like `1 2 4 5 10 33`

Comment: @depperm how should the user input the data so the error doesn't happen

Answer (score 3):

You've used the wrong syntax.  I believe that what you're trying to do is to initialize both `min` and `max` to the first element of the list.  The assignment you used is for multiple assignment -- with two variables on the left, you must have two values on the right.

However you want the user to enter the input is fine; simply `split` the input on the delimiter you choose, and then use that for `split`.

Also, remember to convert the values from string to int (left as an exercise for the student).

The important syntax for the error you gave is

```
min = max = data[0]
```

*Now* you can continue with your loop.

Comment: Note: [`ast.literal_eval` is usually a good way to parse the input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (so entering `12, 25, 39, 1, 3, -2, 102, -5` produces a `tuple` of `int`s). As is, the OP's code is computing the min and max character from a string, not parsing the string to a useful "list" of values.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: that's why I recommended convert to `int`.  Others have already covered the input problem, so I decided not to belabour the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are bugs in your code:

1. You should define your list format. Such as input numbers are separated by ",","" etc.
2. when you assign `data[0]` to `min` and `max`, you have to put `=` between `min` and `max`.

Please make changes in your code as shown below:

```
data =[int(x) for x in input().split(",")]
max = min = data[0]
```

Please provide the `input` list as `number1`, `number2`, `number3` etc.

This will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a tuple that holds your input items in the form (1, 2). You are doing `data[0]` which means you are getting the first item from `data` tuple, which is just one item, not two. Then with the command `max, min = data[0]` you are telling python to extract two items from one item `data[0]`.

Instead use:

```
max, min = data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not converted the input into a list, and you have defined min and max in a wrong way.

Do this to convert inputs into list:

```
data.split(" ") #if every number is separated by space
```

And for min and max, you're assigning two value by saying

```
min, max= data[0]
```

do it like this:

```
min=max=data[0]
```

You can cheat on this program in a way, if only condition is not using min and max function. You're sorting the list in a manner. However you can also do this:

```
def minmax():
    data = input("Enter a list of any input > ")
    myList= data.split(" ")
    myList.sort()
    print(myList[0], "is minimum and", myList[-1],"is max")
minmax()
```